# What does @Deprecated mean on method parameters and local variables?

Tags: java, deprecated

DISCLAIMER: I know the meaning and purpose of `@Deprecated`.

The definition of the `@Deprecated` annotation looks like this in the source code of Java:

```java
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(value={CONSTRUCTOR, FIELD, LOCAL_VARIABLE, METHOD, PACKAGE, PARAMETER, TYPE})
public @interface Deprecated {
}
```

I understand the purpose of having target values of `CONSTRUCTOR`, `FIELD`, `TYPE`, `METHOD` and `PACKAGE`.

However, what does it mean to mark a method parameter or a local variable as `@Deprecated`?

Strangely the below example compiles without any warnings.

```java
interface Doable {
    void doIt(@Deprecated Object input);
}

class Action implements Doable {

    @Override
    public void doIt(@Deprecated Object input) {

        String string = String.valueOf(input); // no warning!

        @Deprecated
        String localVariable = "hello";

        System.out.println("Am I using a deprecated variable?" + localVariable); // no warning!
    }
}
```

Is this something they might intend to implement in the future?

---

FWIW, I use JDK 1.7.0_11 on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit. The result is the same whether I run the program from Eclipse or command line.

The compiler does spit out warnings for *normal* usage of `@Deprecated`, such as using one of the deprecated constructors of the `java.util.Date` class. Just to prove that I don't have a faulty terminal or set up, here is the output:

```
$ javac com/adarshr/Test.java -Xlint:deprecation
com/adarshr/Test.java:12: warning: [deprecation] Date(int,int,int) in Date has been deprecated
        new Date(2013, 1, 31);
        ^
1 warning
$ 
$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_11
```

Comment: Just for curiosity, which compiler are you using? and when you write `//no warning` are you inside an IDE?

Comment: I struggle to understand what a non deprecated method with a deprecated argument can mean...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What does it mean to mark a method parameter or a local variable as `@Deprecated`?

It has [the same meaning as when applied to any other element:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html)

> A program element annotated `@Deprecated` is one that programmers are discouraged from using, typically because it is dangerous, or because a better alternative exists. Compilers warn when a deprecated program element is used or overridden in non-deprecated code.

---

Why doesn't the compiler omit warnings for deprecated parameters and fields in Java 7?
[Because that's exactly what the JLS (§ 9.6.3.6) dictates.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.3.6)

> A Java compiler must produce a deprecation warning when a type, method, field, or constructor whose declaration is annotated with the annotation `@Deprecated` is used (i.e. overridden, invoked, or referenced by name), unless:
>
> - The use is within an entity that is itself annotated with the annotation @Deprecated; or
> - The use is within an entity that is annotated to suppress the warning with the annotation `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`; or
> - The use and declaration are both within the same outermost class.
>
> **Use of the `@Deprecated` annotation on a local variable declaration or on a parameter declaration has no effect.**

(emphasis added)

Comment: Exactly. But `Compilers warn when a deprecated program element is used or overridden in non-deprecated code` never happens when you use `@Deprecated` on method parameters or local variables!

Comment: You must be seeing that inside of Eclipse; I see the same. When I compile with javac, however, I do get a warning.

Comment: I'm sure it happens with Java 6, which is how I just tested it.

Comment: In Java 6 [there is no target](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Deprecated.java) - not sure if that has an impact.

Comment: @adarshr found it in the JLS `:)`

Comment: `Use of the @Deprecated annotation on a local variable declaration or on a parameter declaration has no effect.` is the one! It must be reserved for the future :)

Comment: @adarshr - unless you can think of a use that doesn't involve emitting a warning, then I doubt it.  The Java maintainers are unlikely to mandate a language change where a construct that was specified as ignored is no longer ignored.  It breaks source-level compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

The JLS expressly states that the @Deprecation annotation is ignored on local variables.  See Matt Ball's answer.

> Is this something they might intend to implement in the future?

I very much doubt it.

- What could it mean ... apart from its current meaning as an informal reminder to the implementor (and maybe style checkers / PMD / FindBugs / etc) that the local variable needs to be removed.
- Any *material* change is likely to break source compatibility for people who currently use the annotation as above.  The Java maintainers try very hard to avoid breaking old code.

Answer (score 0):

If you compile such a code (ex:mvn clean compile) you get following warning message

`@Deprecated annotation has no effect on this variable declaration`

meaning its useless :)